# SQL Server Startup Paramenter

Tags: sql, sql-server

I found the following value in my  SQL server Startup paramenter what is the meaning of that:

> -T1118

Comment: @user137520 : Looks to me like Oded has a very acceptable answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/psssql/sql-server-2005-and-2008-trace-flag-1118-t1118-usage) blog post:

> Trace flag 1118 forces uniform extent allocations instead of mixed page allocations.   The trace flag is commonly used to assist in TEMPDB scalability by avoiding SGAM and other allocation contention points.

Answer (score 2):

Suggest you have a look at [Paul Randalls blog post](http://sqlskills.com/BLOGS/PAUL/post/Misconceptions-around-TF-1118.aspx)